# RestEasy TJWS base path

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy, tjws

I'm creating an embedded server using JBoss RestEasy's embedded TJWS. The limited documentation is inaccurate, but I was able to create a server instance with a test JAX-RS resource:

```
@Path("test")
public class TestResource {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer tjws = new TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer();
    tjws.setPort(8080);
    tjws.start();
    tjws.getDeployment().getRegistry().addPerRequestResource(TestResource.class);
  }
  ...
```

That allows me to browse to `http://localhost:8080/test` to test the `GET` method implementation (not shown here).

But how do I specify that the embedded server should be mounted at some other base path? For example, how do I get the test resource mounted to `http://localhost:8080/example/test`? Sure, I could hard code this into the `@Path` designation, but the base path shouldn't be part of the resource---I should be able to redeploy this resource class in a J2EE server at any base path.

I'm guessing there is something like a `tjws.getDeployment().setBasePath("example")` that I haven't found, yet. (If anybody has some in-depth documentation for this please let me know as well!) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So far I've found that I can simulate this by specifying a prefix when adding resources to the server:

```
tjws.getDeployment().getRegistry().addPerRequestResource(TestResource.class, "example");
```

That's not quite the same as I was looking for, but it does allow me to access the resource as `http://localhost:8080/example/test` without being forced to indicate this base path in the resource definition.